# Avoid reporting Broken Pipe errors to Sentry in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sentry

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Sentry for exception tracking and I'm getting some errors that look like this:

```
ClientAbortExceptionorg.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer in realWriteBytes
errorjava.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

My understanding is that it's just a networking error and thus I should generally ignore them. What I want to do is report all other `IOExceptions` and log broken pipes to Librato so I can keep an eye on how many I'm getting (a spike might mean there's an issue with the client, which is also developed by me in Java):

I came up with this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Priority(1)
@Order(1)
public class RestExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(ClientAbortException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleClientAbortException(ClientAbortException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Throwable rootCause = ex;
        while (ex.getCause() != null) {
            rootCause = ex.getCause();
        }
        if (rootCause.getMessage().contains("Broken pipe")) {
            logger.info("count#broken_pipe=1");
        } else {
            Sentry.getStoredClient().sendException(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is that an acceptable way to deal with this problem?

I have Sentry configured following the documentation this way:

```
@Configuration
public class FactoryBeanAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver sentryExceptionResolver() {
        return new SentryExceptionResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer sentryServletContextInitializer() {
        return new SentryServletContextInitializer();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see an issue with the code sample provided, but how is Sentry configured in the rest of the application? If something somewhere else is capturing exceptions and sending them to Sentry then this wouldn't prevent that from happening. Or are you using a Sentry logging integration and only sending things that ERROR or above?

Comment: @Brett: thank you for the comment. I added that information to the question.

Comment: I think that by returning `null` you're telling Spring to run the other handlers, which seems like it would run the Sentry resolver which would send it to Sentry anyway? You may need to return a valid `ResponseEntity` instead? At least that's what I found when implementing the Sentry resolver: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/f57a8e7020527ff077cff4400faabae631560289/sentry-spring/src/main/java/io/sentry/spring/SentryExceptionResolver.java#L26-L27

Comment: @Pablo, I assume this is not working and still sending the request to Sentry?

Comment: @TarunLalwani: I don't know, because it's not easy to test.

Comment: @Pablo, you can create a test endpoint and inside that raise a exception `throw new ClientAbortException("exception", new IOException("Broken pipe"))`

Comment: @Pablo could you please elaborate a bit more on how your infrastructure looks like. Broken Pipe usually means that client terminated a connection (e.g. by sending RST packet instead of graceful close with FIN). I had funny case (±40k broken pipes per day) with HaProxy and Netty based backend. Reason - HaProxy configured to use HTTP1.1 with HTTP KeepAlive for heartbeat checks (it closed connection with RST), switch to Http 1.0 solved 99% of them, rest was handled by closing Idle connections from backend side before balancer did it.

Comment: Hi, I wonder whether we should ignore "broken pipe" error or should report it? Because by default, Sentry and also Elastic APM both report this as error. Personally I think we should ignore it, but why do the two libraries report it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the class `SentryExceptionResolver`

```
public class SentryExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver, Ordered {
    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
                                         HttpServletResponse response,
                                         Object handler,
                                         Exception ex) {

        Sentry.capture(ex);

        // null = run other HandlerExceptionResolvers to actually handle the exception
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        // ensure this resolver runs first so that all exceptions are reported
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}
```

By returning `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in `getOrder` it makes sure that it gets called first. Even though you have set the `Priority` to `1`, it won't work. So you want to change your

```
@Configuration
public class FactoryBeanAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver sentryExceptionResolver() {
        return new SentryExceptionResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer sentryServletContextInitializer() {
        return new SentryServletContextInitializer();
    }
}
```

to

```
@Configuration
public class FactoryBeanAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver sentryExceptionResolver() {
        return new SentryExceptionResolver() {
                @Override
                public int getOrder() {
                    // ensure we can get some resolver earlier than this
                    return 10;
                }
         };
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer sentryServletContextInitializer() {
        return new SentryServletContextInitializer();
    }
}
```

This will ensure you can have your handler can be run earlier. In your code the loop to get `rootCause` is incorrect

```
while (ex.getCause() != null) {
    rootCause = ex.getCause();
}
```

This is a infinite loop as you have used `ex` instead of `rootCause`. Even if you correct it, it can still become an infinite loop. When the exception cause returns itself it will be stuck. I have not thoroughly tested it but I believe it should be like below

```
while (rootCause.getCause() != null && rootCause.getCause() != rootCause) {
    rootCause = rootCause.getCause();
}
```

The is one way of solving your problem. But you need to send the exception yourself to Sentry. So there is another way to handle your requirement

**Way 2**

In this case you can do the whole logic in your Configuration and change it to below

```
@Configuration
public class FactoryBeanAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver sentryExceptionResolver() {
        return new SentryExceptionResolver() {
            @Override
            public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response,
                    Object handler,
                    Exception ex) {
                Throwable rootCause = ex;

                while (rootCause .getCause() != null && rootCause.getCause() != rootCause) {
                    rootCause = rootCause.getCause();
                }

                if (!rootCause.getMessage().contains("Broken pipe")) {
                    super.resolveException(request, response, handler, ex);
                }
                return null;
            }   

        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer sentryServletContextInitializer() {
        return new SentryServletContextInitializer();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was reviewing this code and for getting to the bottom exception, shouldn't it be doing `rootCause = rootCause.getCause();`. Otherwise, it can only go one step as `ex` never changes.

Comment: @pupeno, yes you are right. When I tested it only had one level deep exception, so didn't catch this. It should be indeed `rootCause = rootCause.getCause();`

Comment: Cool! I corrected the answer. Surprisingly, I copied the code and just by luck I only ever had to deal with two levels (until now), so, I was very confused.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Good that the error occurred and you could notice the issue :-)

Comment: Hi, I wonder whether we should ignore "broken pipe" error or should report it? Because by default, Sentry and also Elastic APM both report this as error. Personally I think we should ignore it, but why do the two libraries report it?

Comment: In the latest version of Sentry for Spring Boot, the order is not hard-coded to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, but can be configured with the `sentry.exception-resolver-order` property.